# How can I code a hyperlink to open an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to figure out how to open link "Watch & Shop" to display my iframe. On this page
https://www.neostrata.com/past-live-shows.html.

When I click on the portrait images I can get the iframe to open up, but when I click on 'Watch & Shop" now link, it just refreshes the page.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Past Live Shows</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="contenthub-wrapper">
   <div class="module-e callout-content ch-ap-page-header">
      <div class="contenthub-article-page-banner ">
         <div class="ch-article-page-banner-bg">
            <picture>
               <source>
               <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="//neutrogena.imgix.net/neostrata/Landing_pages/neo_livepage_desktop_herobanner-min.jpg">
               <source media="(max-width: 767px)" srcset="//neutrogena.imgix.net/neostrata/Landing_pages/neo_livepage_mobile_herobanner-min.jpg">
               <img alt="" class="lazyloaded" src="null">
            </picture>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="list-heading bg-prestige text-center" id="head-subtitle-wrap">
          <p class="f-gothamlight fc-white">Discover skincare tips and expert picks!</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="ch-ap-content-body f-gothamlight">
         <div class="list-heading text-center n-my-3">
            <!-- <h2 class="title" role="presentation">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2> -->
            <h2 class="title" role="presentation">Watch what you missed</h2>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ch-ap-content-body f-gothamlight full-width">
         <div class="vid-tiles-wrapper">
            <div class="vid-tile">
                 <a role="button" class="toggle-dialog">
                    <img src="//neutrogena.imgix.net/neostrata/pages/live-shows/neo_videocover_pat-min.jpg">
                </a>
                <p class="host-name">Patricia Clare, <br>NEOSTRATA Canada Education Manager</p>
                <small><strong>from December 8<sup>th</sup>, 2021</strong></small>
                <p class="sub"><span>Holiday Skincare Tips</span></p>
                <p><a href="#" class="uppercase">Watch & Shop</a></p>
               <div class="inner-modal">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                     <a class="close-dialog">+</a>
                      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8m8QR5pIOpQ" title="Holiday Skincare Tips" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>



            <div class="vid-tile">
                <a role="button" class="toggle-dialog">
                    <img src="//neutrogena.imgix.net/neostrata/pages/live-shows/neo_videocover_Joy-min.jpg">
                </a>
                <p class="host-name">Joy Ogunneye, <br>NEOSTRATA Senior Brand Manager</p>
                <small><strong>from November 18<sup>th</sup>, 2021</strong></small>
                <p class="sub"><span>Holiday Tips</span></p>
                <p><a href="#" class="uppercase">Watch & Shop</a></p>
               <div class="inner-modal">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                     <a class="close-dialog">+</a>
                   <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/B6nADWJ-TOI" title="Holiday Tips" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
              </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="ch-ap-content-body f-gothamlight full-width">
         <div class="vid-tiles-wrapper">
            <div class="vid-tile">
                 <a role="button" class="toggle-dialog">
                    <img src="//neutrogena.imgix.net/neostrata/pages/live-shows/neo_videocover_jackie2-min.jpg">
                </a>
                <p class="host-name">Jacquie Hutchinson, <br>NEOSTRATA Brand Educator</p>
                <small><strong>from October 20<sup>th</sup>, 2021</strong></small>
                <p class="sub"><span>Winter Skincare Secrets</span></p>
                <p><a href="#" class="uppercase">Watch & Shop</a></p>
               <div class="inner-modal">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                     <a class="close-dialog">+</a>
                      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vDAcdKVExJU" title="Winter Skincare Secrets" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>

      <div class="ch-ap-content-body f-gothamlight full-width">
         <div class="vid-tiles-wrapper">
            <div class="vid-tile">
                <a role="button" class="toggle-dialog">
                    <img src="//neutrogena.imgix.net/neostrata/pages/live-shows/neo_videocover_jacquie1-min.jpg">
                </a>
                <p class="host-name">Jacquie Hutchinson, <br>NEOSTRATA Brand Educator</p>
                <small><strong>from August 17<sup>th</sup>, 2021</strong></small>
                <p class="sub"><span>Correct Collection Launch Party</span></p>
                <p><a href="#" class="uppercase">Watch & Shop</a></p>
               <div class="inner-modal">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                     <a class="close-dialog">+</a>
                     <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wv3RbQliE98" title="Correct Launch Party" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>



 <div class="ch-ap-content-body f-gothamlight full-width">
         <div class="vid-tiles-wrapper">
            <div class="vid-tile">
              <a role="button" class="toggle-dialog">
                    <img src="//neutrogena.imgix.net/neostrata/pages/live-shows/neo_videocover_kim1-min.jpg">
                </a>
                <p class="host-name">Kim Sarros, <br>NEOSTRATA Global Educator</p>
                <small><strong>from July 8<sup>th</sup>, 2021</strong></small>
                <p class="sub"><span>Summer Skincare Essentials</span></p>
                <p><a href="#" class="uppercase">Watch & Shop</a></p>
               <div class="inner-modal">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                     <a class="close-dialog">+</a>
                      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3Lb3URM7nag" title="Kim's Summer Skincare Essentials" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
  </div>
           </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
    
      <div class="ch-ap-content-body f-gothamlight full-width">
        <br>
         <h2 class="title text-center" role="presentation">SHOP JOY’S PICKS FOR GLOWING SKIN</h2>
         <div class="hide-add-all">
            $include('Page-ShopStory', 'pids', 'F30150R--F30101XA--F30151R--F30107XA')$
$include('Page-Include','cid','past-live-shows-includes')$
          </div>
 <div class="ch-ap-content-body f-gothamlight full-width">
        <br>
         <h2 class="title text-center" role="presentation">SHOP JACQUIE’S MUST-HAVES</h2>
         <div class="hide-add-all">
            $include('Page-ShopStory', 'pids', 'F30104XA--F30102XA--F30149XB--F30136XA')$
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
$include('Page-Include','cid','past-live-shows-includes')$
 <div class="ch-ap-content-body f-gothamlight full-width">
        <br>
          <h2 class="title text-center" role="presentation">SHOP KIM’S SUMMER SKINCARE ESSENTIALS</h2>
         <div class="hide-add-all">
            $include('Page-ShopStory', 'pids', 'F30150R--F30145XA--F30164U--F30156XA--F30155R')$
         </div>
      <div class="ch-ap-content-body f-gothamlight full-width">
        <br>
         <h2 class="title text-center" role="presentation">SHOP PATRICIA'S HOLIDAY SKINCARE FAVORITES</h2>
         <div class="hide-add-all">
            $include('Page-ShopStory', 'pids', 'F30101XA--F30159XA--F30119XA--F30107XA')$
$include('Page-Include','cid','past-live-shows-includes')$
          </div>
$include('Page-Include','cid','past-live-shows-includes')$
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now your "Watch and Shop" links have no destination. You need to include each of these URLs in the href attribute. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Past Live Shows</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="contenthub-wrapper">
   <div class="module-e callout-content ch-ap-page-header">
      <div class="contenthub-article-page-banner ">
         <div class="ch-article-page-banner-bg">
            <picture>
               <source>
               <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="//neutrogena.imgix.net/neostrata/Landing_pages/neo_livepage_desktop_herobanner-min.jpg">
               <source media="(max-width: 767px)" srcset="//neutrogena.imgix.net/neostrata/Landing_pages/neo_livepage_mobile_herobanner-min.jpg">
               <img alt="" class="lazyloaded" src="null">
            </picture>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="list-heading bg-prestige text-center" id="head-subtitle-wrap">
          <p class="f-gothamlight fc-white">Discover skincare tips and expert picks!</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="ch-ap-content-body f-gothamlight">
         <div class="list-heading text-center n-my-3">
            <!-- <h2 class="title" role="presentation">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2> -->
            <h2 class="title" role="presentation">Watch what you missed</h2>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ch-ap-content-body f-gothamlight full-width">
         <div class="vid-tiles-wrapper">
            <div class="vid-tile">
                 <a role="button" class="toggle-dialog">
                    <img src="//neutrogena.imgix.net/neostrata/pages/live-shows/neo_videocover_pat-min.jpg">
                </a>
                <p class="host-name">Patricia Clare, <br>NEOSTRATA Canada Education Manager</p>
                <small><strong>from December 8<sup>th</sup>, 2021</strong></small>
                <p class="sub"><span>Holiday Skincare Tips</span></p>
                <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8m8QR5pIOpQ" class="uppercase">Watch & Shop</a></p>
               <div class="inner-modal">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                     <a class="close-dialog">+</a>
                      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8m8QR5pIOpQ" title="Holiday Skincare Tips" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>



            <div class="vid-tile">
                <a role="button" class="toggle-dialog">
                    <img src="//neutrogena.imgix.net/neostrata/pages/live-shows/neo_videocover_Joy-min.jpg">
                </a>
                <p class="host-name">Joy Ogunneye, <br>NEOSTRATA Senior Brand Manager</p>
                <small><strong>from November 18<sup>th</sup>, 2021</strong></small>
                <p class="sub"><span>Holiday Tips</span></p>
                <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/B6nADWJ-TOI" class="uppercase">Watch & Shop</a></p>
               <div class="inner-modal">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                     <a class="close-dialog">+</a>
                   <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/B6nADWJ-TOI" title="Holiday Tips" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
              </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="ch-ap-content-body f-gothamlight full-width">
         <div class="vid-tiles-wrapper">
            <div class="vid-tile">
                 <a role="button" class="toggle-dialog">
                    <img src="//neutrogena.imgix.net/neostrata/pages/live-shows/neo_videocover_jackie2-min.jpg">
                </a>
                <p class="host-name">Jacquie Hutchinson, <br>NEOSTRATA Brand Educator</p>
                <small><strong>from October 20<sup>th</sup>, 2021</strong></small>
                <p class="sub"><span>Winter Skincare Secrets</span></p>
                <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vDAcdKVExJU" class="uppercase">Watch & Shop</a></p>
               <div class="inner-modal">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                     <a class="close-dialog">+</a>
                      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vDAcdKVExJU" title="Winter Skincare Secrets" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>

      <div class="ch-ap-content-body f-gothamlight full-width">
         <div class="vid-tiles-wrapper">
            <div class="vid-tile">
                <a role="button" class="toggle-dialog">
                    <img src="//neutrogena.imgix.net/neostrata/pages/live-shows/neo_videocover_jacquie1-min.jpg">
                </a>
                <p class="host-name">Jacquie Hutchinson, <br>NEOSTRATA Brand Educator</p>
                <small><strong>from August 17<sup>th</sup>, 2021</strong></small>
                <p class="sub"><span>Correct Collection Launch Party</span></p>
                <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wv3RbQliE98" class="uppercase">Watch & Shop</a></p>
               <div class="inner-modal">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                     <a class="close-dialog">+</a>
                     <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wv3RbQliE98" title="Correct Launch Party" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>



 <div class="ch-ap-content-body f-gothamlight full-width">
         <div class="vid-tiles-wrapper">
            <div class="vid-tile">
              <a role="button" class="toggle-dialog">
                    <img src="//neutrogena.imgix.net/neostrata/pages/live-shows/neo_videocover_kim1-min.jpg">
                </a>
                <p class="host-name">Kim Sarros, <br>NEOSTRATA Global Educator</p>
                <small><strong>from July 8<sup>th</sup>, 2021</strong></small>
                <p class="sub"><span>Summer Skincare Essentials</span></p>
                <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3Lb3URM7nag" class="uppercase">Watch & Shop</a></p>
               <div class="inner-modal">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                     <a class="close-dialog">+</a>
                      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3Lb3URM7nag" title="Kim's Summer Skincare Essentials" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
  </div>
           </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
    
      <div class="ch-ap-content-body f-gothamlight full-width">
        <br>
         <h2 class="title text-center" role="presentation">SHOP JOY’S PICKS FOR GLOWING SKIN</h2>
         <div class="hide-add-all">
            $include('Page-ShopStory', 'pids', 'F30150R--F30101XA--F30151R--F30107XA')$
$include('Page-Include','cid','past-live-shows-includes')$
          </div>
 <div class="ch-ap-content-body f-gothamlight full-width">
        <br>
         <h2 class="title text-center" role="presentation">SHOP JACQUIE’S MUST-HAVES</h2>
         <div class="hide-add-all">
            $include('Page-ShopStory', 'pids', 'F30104XA--F30102XA--F30149XB--F30136XA')$
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
$include('Page-Include','cid','past-live-shows-includes')$
 <div class="ch-ap-content-body f-gothamlight full-width">
        <br>
          <h2 class="title text-center" role="presentation">SHOP KIM’S SUMMER SKINCARE ESSENTIALS</h2>
         <div class="hide-add-all">
            $include('Page-ShopStory', 'pids', 'F30150R--F30145XA--F30164U--F30156XA--F30155R')$
         </div>
      <div class="ch-ap-content-body f-gothamlight full-width">
        <br>
         <h2 class="title text-center" role="presentation">SHOP PATRICIA'S HOLIDAY SKINCARE FAVORITES</h2>
         <div class="hide-add-all">
            $include('Page-ShopStory', 'pids', 'F30101XA--F30159XA--F30119XA--F30107XA')$
$include('Page-Include','cid','past-live-shows-includes')$
          </div>
$include('Page-Include','cid','past-live-shows-includes')$
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please update your snippet with the correct code? It is difficult to understand these comments.